# Locate a number in an array with a special ordering

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Below are two examples of arrays (with a special ordering with odd numbers on one side, and even number on the other side) I have, with some given `length`:

Two examples:

```
9   7   5   3   1   2   4   6   8

11  9   7   5   3   1   2   4   6   8   10
```

For some value `z`, I want to find the column the value is in. MATLAB code I wrote:

```
if z == 1
   column = ceil(length/2);   
elseif logical(mod(z,2))
   column = ceil(length/2) - (z-1)/2;
else
   column = ceil(length/2) + z/2;
end
```

It is correct I think for most cases. Also, is there an elegant one-liner in MATLAB that can do this?

Comment: If I my answer worked for you, would you mind marking it as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could subtract the value you're looking for from the array and find where it is zero (in the case of the exact value existing in the array and/or integers) or find where it is less than some tolerance value.

For integers:

```
a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
z = 6;
[row column] = find((a-z) == 0)
```

I am realizing the below code may not be very useful, but it will find the values within the tolerance of the value `z`:

```
[row column] = find(abs(a-z) < tolerance)
```

Does that do what you want?